# Authorship Attribution using Machine Learning

Tags: machine-learning, classification, text-mining, text-classification, document-classification

I am working on a practical machine learning problem as an exercise. I just need help formulating my problem.

I have text from 20 books of a famous old Author. there are 5 more books that has been debated throughout history if the belong to the same author or not.

I am thinking about the best way to represent this problem. I am thinking of using a bag-of-words appoach to find the most significant words used by the author.

Should I treat it as a Naive Bayes (Spam/Ham) problem, or should I use KNN classification (Author/non-author) to detect the class of each document. Is there another way of doing it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think Naive Bayes can give you insights. One more way can be , find out features which separate such books ex
1. Complexity of words , some writers are easy to understand and use common words , i am hinting towards IDF (Inverse document frequency)
2. Some words may not not even exist at his time like "selfie" , "mobile" etc.

Try to find a lot of features like that and can also train a discriminative classifier.